# Uploaded Photo with iPad is rotate

Tags: php, javascript, image, exif

I need a PHP script to rotate my uploaded images on server with iPad. I have a problem with orientation of image and exif data. I try maybe a 10 solutions and don't have a solution. When the "button" is on the right side, the uploaded image was OK, but if I rotate iPad then i images rotate and i can't display them normaly..Any help ?

Comment: I didn't understand the question,what do you mean rotate uploaded image on server with iPad?

Comment: my english is bad, but if I take a picture with Ipad adn then upload on server, image isn't in normal orientation, do you understand my problem ?

Comment: Still foggy,i think it is all about your iPad,not the server..maybe from the camera rotation,you can just simply edit it inside the iPad and rotate it.

Comment: No, i have web aplication, developed in PHP, on the front, user can on <input type="file"/> choose a photo or take a photo, and when iPad is not in position "button on right side" then uploaded image also have a wrong orientation.

Comment: this happened to me as well, in web application when you upload an image using ipad it will have an orientation problem.

Answer (score 6):

Here you go, i decided to have a play since i had a spare 30 minutes to kill

https://github.com/leesherwood/Orientation-Fix-PHP

Just pass the file path into the `fix_orientation` function, and it should work (check the code and function comments, you will probably want to edit how it finally saves the image such as the name or whatever)

And for those that just want the code or github dies, heres the main function file for you

```
    <?php
/*
 * PHP Orientation Fix (GD) v1.0.0
 * https://github.com/leesherwood/Orientation-Fix-PHP
 *
 * Copyright 2013, "leesherwood" Lee Sherwood
 *
 * Licensed under the MIT license:
 * http://www.opensource.org/licenses/MIT
 *
 * AKA: I couldn't care less what you do with it, 
 *      im just a nice guy and i want to share.
 *      But it would be nice if you left me a little credit :)
 *
 * If you use this, then let me know at: i-played-with-your-git@secure4sure.org
 */

/**
 * The main function that does the actual job
 * 
 * Pass a string representing the image path and filename such as /var/www/images/image.jpg
 * And it will change the name of the image to include "orig." (for the sake of not deleting your image if something goes wrong)
 * and then create a new image with the same filename, with the orientation fixed
 * The return bool is not informative and should only be used to to tell your script that there is a proper orientated image available (or not)
 * If you want to know why it failed (theres many reason) then you need to make the return values for informative, or use exceptions.     
 *   
 * @param string the path to the file including the file iteself (absolute path would be advised)
 * @return bool true if successful, false if not
 */  
function fix_orientation($fileandpath) {

  // Does the file exist to start with?
  if(!file_exists($fileandpath))
    return false;

  // Get all the exif data from the file
  $exif = read_exif_data($fileandpath, 'IFD0');

  // If we dont get any exif data at all, then we may as well stop now
  if(!$exif || !is_array($exif))
    return false;

  // I hate case juggling, so we're using loweercase throughout just in case
  $exif = array_change_key_case($exif, CASE_LOWER);

  // If theres no orientation key, then we can give up, the camera hasn't told us the 
  // orientation of itself when taking the image, and i'm not writing a script to guess at it!
  if(!array_key_exists('orientation', $exif)) 
    return false;

  // Gets the GD image resource for loaded image
  $img_res = get_image_resource($fileandpath);

  // If it failed to load a resource, give up
  if(is_null($img_res))
    return false;

  // The meat of the script really, the orientation is supplied as an integer, 
  // so we just rotate/flip it back to the correct orientation based on what we 
  // are told it currently is 
  switch($exif['orientation']) {

    // Standard/Normal Orientation (no need to do anything, we'll return true as in theory, it was successful)
    case 1: return true; break;

    // Correct orientation, but flipped on the horizontal axis (might do it at some point in the future)
    case 2: 
      $final_img = imageflip($img_res, IMG_FLIP_HORIZONTAL);
    break;

    // Upside-Down
    case 3: 
      $final_img = imageflip($img_res, IMG_FLIP_VERTICAL);
    break;

    // Upside-Down & Flipped along horizontal axis
    case 4:  
      $final_img = imageflip($img_res, IMG_FLIP_BOTH);
    break;

    // Turned 90 deg to the left and flipped
    case 5:  
      $final_img = imagerotate($img_res, -90, 0);
      $final_img = imageflip($img_res, IMG_FLIP_HORIZONTAL);
    break;

    // Turned 90 deg to the left
    case 6: 
      $final_img = imagerotate($img_res, -90, 0);
    break;

    // Turned 90 deg to the right and flipped
    case 7: 
      $final_img = imagerotate($img_res, 90, 0);
      $final_img = imageflip($img_res,IMG_FLIP_HORIZONTAL);
    break;

    // Turned 90 deg to the right
    case 8: 
      $final_img = imagerotate($img_res, 90, 0); 
    break;

  }

  // If theres no final image resource to output for whatever reason, give up
  if(!isset($final_img))
    return false;

  //-- rename original (very ugly, could probably be rewritten, but i can't be arsed at this stage)
  $parts = explode("/", $fileandpath);
  $oldname = array_pop($parts);
  $path = implode('/', $parts);
  $oldname_parts = explode(".", $oldname);
  $ext = array_pop($oldname_parts);
  $newname = implode('.', $oldname_parts).'.orig.'.$ext;

  rename($fileandpath, $path.'/'.$newname);

  // Save it and the return the result (true or false)
  $done = save_image_resource($final_img,$fileandpath);

  return $done;

}

/**
 * Simple function which takes the filepath, grabs the extension and returns the GD resource for it
 * Not fool-proof nor the best, but it does the job for now 
 */ 
function get_image_resource($file) {

    $img = null;
    $p = explode(".", strtolower($file));
    $ext = array_pop($p);
    switch($ext) {

      case "png":
        $img = imagecreatefrompng($file);
        break;

      case "jpg":
      case "jpeg":
        $img = imagecreatefromjpeg($file);
        break;
      case "gif":
        $img = imagecreatefromgif($file);
        break;

    }  

    return $img;

}

/**
 * Saves the final image resource to the given location
 * As above it works out the extension and bases its output command on that, not fool proof, but works nonetheless
 */  
function save_image_resource($resource, $location) {

    $success = false;
    $p = explode(".", strtolower($location));
    $ext = array_pop($p);
    switch($ext) {

      case "png":
        $success = imagepng($resource,$location);
        break;

      case "jpg":
      case "jpeg":
        $success = imagejpeg($resource,$location);
        break;
      case "gif":
        $success = imagegif($resource,$location);
        break;

    } 

    return $success;

}


/**
 * My Dev environment is not the latest on this machine. which is lucky as i never bothered to check if imageflip needed a specific version
 * ( been using imagerotate for ages and assumed imageflip would surely be included to )
 * But as it turns out, you need a fairly recent version of PHP for imageflip, so i cobbled together a quick replacement function for those that don't have it
 */   
if(!function_exists('imageflip')) {

  // These are the same constants so this script should be upgrade safe, the values are different no doubt, but that won't hurt!
  define("IMG_FLIP_HORIZONTAL", 1);
  define("IMG_FLIP_VERTICAL", 2);
  define("IMG_FLIP_BOTH", 3);

  /**
   * Simple function that takes a gd image resource and the flip mode, and uses rotate 180 instead to do the same thing... Simples!
   */     
  function imageflip($resource, $mode) {

      if($mode == IMG_FLIP_VERTICAL || $mode == IMG_FLIP_BOTH)
        $resource = imagerotate($resource, 180, 0);

      if($mode == IMG_FLIP_HORIZONTAL || $mode == IMG_FLIP_BOTH)
        $resource = imagerotate($resource, 90, 0);

      return $resource;

  }

}


?>
```

Comment: Thanks. save_image_resource might set third parameter (e.g. quality=0..9 for png) to not loose image quality:

imagejpeg($resource,$location, 100);
imagepng($resource,$location,0);

to deactivate compression.